# Hide/Show Form Elements Not Working on Android App

Tags: javascript, android, html, hide, show-hide

I'm trying to create an interactive form. Your selections determine the next questions that appear. I'm using jQuery Mobile and it is working fine on the PC using Dreamweaver but when I build to Android the java scripts aren't working. This seems like simple code so I'm not sure why it's not working on Android. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's the code:

Javascript:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id=SkillSet data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Skill Set:</legend>
        <a onclick="toggle_visibility('AV');"><input type="checkbox" name="SkillSet" id="SkillSet_0" class="custom" value="" /></a>
        <label for="SkillSet_0">AV</label>
        <a onclick="toggle_visibility('IT');"><input type="checkbox" name="SkillSet" id="SkillSet_1" class="custom" value="" /></a>
        <label for="SkillSet_1">IT</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>


   <div id="IT" style="display:none">
    <hr>

    Blah Blah Blah     
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working about it?.. Also if you are using jQuery mobile then why aren't you taking advantage of the features instead of using the `toggle_visibility()` method?

Comment: What features? I could not find anything else that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting one:

Android web DOES support display:none
And javascript
And jQuery mobile isn't being used

I think it might be because you have an anchor tag around your input. Try putting the onclick event on the checkbox or put something else in the anchor.

EDIT:
Or could it be that there are multiple elements with the same id? Ids are supposed to be unique...

Comment: onClick on the checkbox doesn't work. That's why I used the anchor. Is there an easier way to go about this that I don't know about?

Comment: Interesting. 1. Is there a layer covering the anchor or input? 2. Try it with an onChange event...

Comment: There are no layers covering the anchor or input. onChange not working either. No event in the input field will work. They work in the anchor though. But only on the PC. Once I build to Android and install, it doesn't work in Android.

Comment: I just want to unhide a field (Change display from none to block) when you make a selection. Should be a simple thing but I'm new to Andriod. Not sure why it's not working there.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the functions to window.

```
window.toggle_visibility = function(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
   e=="block" ? e="none" : e="block";
}
```

Although I'm sure there is something simpler with jquery for something like that.

Also, why are your check boxes inside of `a` tags?

Comment: That is how I was telling the div ID to hide or show. When I put the onClick within the input field it wouldn't work. Using your java is not working either. A simplier solution would be great. I have searched and could not find one.